# What "is" means in python if it's not "=="?

Tags: python-2.7

What "is" means in python, if it's actually not equal to "=="?

```
>>> c = 300
>>> b = 300
>>> b == c
True
>>> b is c
False
```

Answer (score 2):

**'is'** is the identity comparison.

**'=='** is the equality comparison.

So in your example you have said

```
b = 300
c = 300
```

They both hold the same value so they are equal in terms of value however, they are still both two separate variables with their own identities, they just share the same value.

If you were to do this:

```
b = 300
c = b
```

b is c would return true.

Comment: == checks in an object for the def __eq__(self, other)

Comment: `b = 300 and c = 300` does not work, can't do assignment on `and` expression

Comment: I didn't mean to use the 'and' operand, I just meant 'and' as in the English word. I've edited my response to better suit your needs.